# How to build workflow with multiple git branch?

Tags: git

I have a project, with 2 branches: develop - it equal test site, master - it equal production site.

When I receive new task, I create new branch from develop, commit, merge no fast-forward to develop. When client accept feature, I merge develop to master (no fast-forward).

But sometimes I have not accepted task, and need to create new branch:

```
   master: --- A
                \
  develop: ----- B --- C ----------------- F
feature-1:              \ --- D --- E --- /
```

From what commit I should do feature-2 branch C or F? For example I finished feature-2 and merged it to develop. If client accept only feature-2, how I should merge it to master without feature-1?

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps it does not matter, as you can use `cherry-pick`.

Comment: Cherry-pick work for one commit as I remember...

Comment: See the docs, e.g. `git cherry-pick master~4 master~2`: Apply the changes introduced by the fifth and third last commits pointed to by master and create 2 new commits with these changes. There are several other possibilities...

Comment: Thank you! I will try this workflow.

Answer (score 1):

We use 3 base branches flow:

```
master ---A---------------------------[C,F]
                                       /
test   ------------C------------------F
                  /                  /
dev    ---B------C-------------E----F
          \_F1__/ \\_F3_      /    /
                   \_F2______/____/
```

We work on `dev` and each branch is started from newest `dev`.

After some time when features are confirmed from QA we batch merge them to `test`. And finally before release we merge `test` to `master`. `dev` then is deleted and re-created from `test`. That way we keep `dev` full of fixes and ugly history, `test` is as usually `pre-staging` that is mostly clean with minor fixes and `master` is very clean without additional fixes (branch re-merges)

Before merging to `test` we do `git rebase -i test` on feature branch to rebase it from newest version of code base and merge only what actually was in that branch.

Comment: Interesting workflow, thank you. Sometimes I have priority task, that need to go to master in another order, they cannot wait while all tests will finished.

Comment: @gvozd1989 Same for us. Then we do as follows: merge to test and to master at once (with first rebasing branch). After each rebase you should check if feature is still working with other code.